# ManyToMany field returns None in unit test

Tags: python, django, django-models

As I'm staging my test with some models that contain a ManyToMany field, I'm checking to see if related model instances are being added to the field. However, upon accessing the ManyToMany field for each model I'm getting the following...

```
menu.Item.None
menu.Ingredient.None
```

What is causing `None` to be returned and what can be done to see the related objects for each respective ManyToMany field?

**tests.py**

```
class TestForm(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        test_chef = User.objects.create_user("test_chef")
        eggs = Ingredient.objects.create(name="Eggs")
        flour = Ingredient.objects.create(name="Flour")
        milk = Ingredient.objects.create(name="Milk")
        butter = Ingredient.objects.create(name="Butter")
        vanilla_extract = Ingredient.objects.create(name="Vanilla Extract")
        sugar = Ingredient.objects.create(name="Sugar")
        cls.item = Item.objects.create(
            name="Crepe",
            description="A thin pancake orginiating from France",
            chef=test_chef,
            created_date=timezone.now(),
            standard=True
        )
        cls.item.ingredients.add(eggs, flour, milk, butter, vanilla_extract, sugar,)
        cls.menu = Menu.objects.create(
            season="Fall"
        )
        cls.menu.items.add(cls.item)

    def test_form(self):
        print(self.menu.items)
        print(self.item.ingredients)
```

**models.py**

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    season = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        unique=True
    )
    items = models.ManyToManyField('Item', related_name='items')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.season

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    chef = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    standard = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField('Ingredient')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You need to add `.all()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a method call like `.all()` to the end, otherwise it is indeed *printed* as `ModelName.None`. The reason this happens is because `self.menu.items` is a *manager*, not a queryset. It is comparable to `MyModel.objects` not yielding any elements.

You thus add:

```
def test_form(self):
    print(self.menu.items.all())
    print(self.item.ingredients.all())
```